# Print attribute of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 classes with:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
```

I need to write code, which will print the value of attribute with the name 'postcode' of 100 users from database.

I have some code on this point, but not sure that it's a good way to solve the problem:

```
@users = User.all
@users.limit(100).each do |user|
  puts "#{user.postcode}" 
end
```

Who has better ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [`pluck`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

```
puts User.limit(100).pluck('postcode')
# or
puts User.joins(:address).limit(100).pluck('addresses.postcode')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pluck is best suited for your scenario.

User.where(condition).pluck(:postcode)

(#where condition is optional)

Event if you want to fetch other column with postcode you can simply include that in pluck. for e.g.

User.where(condition).pluck(:id, :postcode)

(#using multiple column inside pluck will only work with rails4 and above)